# 2D to 3D algorithm development?

Tags: 3d, 2d

I've been trying to find someone to develop an algorithm that can take 3 2D iphone or android pictures (of the foot) and extrapolate them in to an approximate 3D model suitable for 3D printing. Can anyone tell me what area of programming expertise this entails so I can narrow my search, or know where to look? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create 3D model from 2D image](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705377/how-to-create-3d-model-from-2d-image)

Comment: Computer vision expert? I wouldn't be surprised if you need a team. Also, for an object as complex as a foot, I expect you'll need more than three photos. You may need to draw a reference grid on the foot so the computer has clearer reference points.

Comment: Yes thanks for the help Steve! I had no idea this position even existed. I do know however that one other person (there are others out there I imagine) has already done this based on three pictures framed with a white piece of paper (as per your comment a reference grid I assume).  I think they are able to extrapolate beyond what the three pictures provide in data points. Thanks again.