# How to extract a PCD file from my own images?

Tags: c++, ubuntu, point-cloud-library, point-clouds, photogrammetry

I'm using the PCL library [link](http://web.pointclouds.org/documentation/) with Ubuntu 17.04.

I'd like to know if there's a way to create a .pcd file from my personal images.

Every tutorials I've found use pregenerate pcd.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a point cloud in a different format, Cloud Compare found at http://www.danielgm.net/cc/ can do a lot of conversions to the .pcd format.

If you are trying to convert 2d images to a point cloud that would be a different story. You will need some sort of depth information, which will probably be difficult to get. See [Generating point cloud from many 2d images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20314556/generating-point-cloud-from-many-2d-images)

Your best bet might be to gather data using a Kinect or lidar device.

Comment: Yes I'm trying to convert 2d images took from a reflex. I thought that was impossible and I should have had some extra tools... Thanks!