# Is there any algorithm for converting the 2d images into 3d model?

Tags: python, computer-science-theory

Is there any way to convert the 2d images into 3d model? as we know it is possible to develop 2d data from 3 dimensional image but can we do reverse as a part of a coding for a computer science student? this is my assignment.. I will do it by my own I am just not able to find the way or the idea that whether it is possible or not?
Foe example, we have x rays or any 2dimensional image from front and side view... then how can we find the depth of it.

Comment: Well, you can get less information from more information, but the reverse is not generally possible. For the specific case in your case though, the width of the side view would be equal to the depth of the front view.

Comment: There's [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7705377/3d-reconstruction-how-to-create-3d-model-from-2d-image) asking a similar question. The answers provide some insight into the difficulty of this problem. Edit: It's a very hard problem.